# Regex - match a pattern (from capture) before a capture group

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

I have to match text with this scheme:

- capture [\w-/]* which are not ['] (\1)
- capture [']+ which follow (\2)
- and replace \2\1\2 with \1

Example:

my input text is: `l''''text'''`
the right output is: `l'text`

I've tried with:

```py
re.sub(r"(\5)(?=((([\w\-\/](?<!'))+)('+)))", r"\2", text)
```

Comment: @Nic pls add some explanation to your post. And also you can't refer a group before capturing..

Comment: zetysz - Thanks...using this you replace without control, because you can't discriminate between the number of ['] before and after the text...

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I need to remove useless punctuation... In the Italian languge, you have to reduce articles followed by vocals with ['] and in this files I have to manage text with some errors... I have to mantain singles ['] wich follow rules and throw away those wich are superfluous.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - [And also you can't refer a group before capturing..] I was trying this, because I did need to know how many ['] follow a word to remove only the same number of them before the word...

Answer (score 2):

You could match the previously matched quotes after the string:

```
('+)([\w/-]+)\1
```

The `\1` matches the exact same text group 1 matched.

Online demo at https://regex101.com/r/zQ0hM2/2.

Python session demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "l''''text'''"
>>> re.sub(r'''('+)([\w/-]+)\1''', r'\2', text)
"l'text"
```

Comment: for general use `(['"]+)((?:(?!\1).)*)\1`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: but the OP wanted to limit the characters between the quotes to word characters, dashes and slashes.

Comment: I used: '('+)([\w/-]+)\1'

Comment: @NicholasRoveda: `[\w/-]` is a simpler way of spelling the same character group. No need to escape a forward slash, and if you put the dash *last* it doesn't need to be escaped either. I removed the double quote. Quotes are not part of your character group, there is no need to use a negative lookbehind to exclude them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -  segments like: l' ' " "text" " '  are only partially corrected: l''text' I need something that can manage recursion or nest

Comment: @NicholasRoveda: why would you expect that to work? You are not matching double quotes or spaces in your inner group. Only word characters, dashes and slashes are allowed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Even though I used ([' "]+)([\w-\/]+)\1, ' and " are nested so \1 should be reversed

Comment: @NicholasRoveda: mixing quote styles is quite a *different problem*, not one so easily solved with a regex. I'd use a full-on lexical parser then instead. Also, that's not what you asked in your original question. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Ok, thank u, I think I'll call sub more than once to clean the text...